# how do i define props in a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i am new to react and i am trying to use props in a function and i am not sure how to use it. This is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Card.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addBasket } from '../actions/addAction';
function Card({props},{image, title,author,price}) {
    return (
        <div className='card-container'>
            <div className="image-container">
                <img src={props.image} alt='' />
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
                <div className="card-title">
                    <h3>{props.title}</h3> </div>
                <div className="card-author">
                    <h4>{props.author}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="card-price">
                    <h3> <span>£{props.price}</span></h3> </div>
            </div>
            <div className="btn">
                <button>
                    <a onClick={props.addBasket}>
                        Add to Basket
                    </a>
                </button></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(null, { addBasket })(Card);
```

And that's the error i am getting.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

```
 </div>
  <div className="card-content">
   <div className="card-title">
       <h3>{props.title}</h3> </div>
    <div className="card-author">
   <h4>{props.author}</h4>
   </div>
```

Comment: `Card({props},{image, title,author,price}) {` remove `{props},`, that's all

Comment: if i delete props it says props is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
function Card({props},{image, title,author,price}) {
```

with

```
function Card(props) {
```

I recommend working through the [official React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) before using Redux.